# CodeIgniter PHPWord using as third_party

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpword

I am trying to use PHPWord and having a difficulties to use it.

This my code within application/libraries/words.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once APPPATH."/third_party/PhpWord/Autoloader.php"; 

\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Autoloader::register(); \\NOT SURE IF THIS IS CORRECT

class Word extends PhpWord { 
    public function __construct() { 
        parent::__construct(); 
    } 
}
```

Based on PHPWord github, i must use it like this:

```
Alternatively, you can download the latest release from the releases page. In this case, you will have to register the autoloader.

require_once 'path/to/PhpWord/src/PhpWord/Autoloader.php';
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Autoloader::register(); // WHERE SHOULD I PUT THIS?
```

When i try to load the library from my controller as such:

```
$this->load->library('word');
```

it gives me error that says:

```
Fatal error: Class 'PhpWord' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\path\to\application\libraries\Word.php on line 7
```

i tried to extends the Autoloader class, but PHP still complains that it can't found Autoloader.php.

when i do

```
file_exist(APPPATH."/third_party/PhpWord/Autoloader.php") // Similarly with PhpWord.php
```

it returns 1.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: did you try `Autoloader::register();` only?

Comment: @kumar_v it says Class 'Autoloader' not found. I tried file_exist(APPPATH."/third_party/PhpWord/Autoloader.php") and it returns 1.

Comment: do you have class Autoloader in Autoloader.php?

Comment: @kumar_v yup, this is the content of it https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/master/src/PhpWord/Autoloader.php

Comment: did u find a solution @JeremyRIrawan??

Comment: @Periback no i didn't. I ended up not using at the moment.

Answer (score 7):

From Russia with love;)
Use like this in library for CodeIgniter:

```
<?php 
    if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


    require_once  APPPATH.'/libraries/PHPWord/src/PhpWord/Autoloader.php';
    use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Autoloader as Autoloader;
    Autoloader::register();

    class Word extends Autoloader {

    }

    ?>
```

In controller like code from samples:

```
$this->load->library('word');
/* remove ;)
#require_once 'PHPWord/src/PhpWord/Autoloader.php';
#PhpOffice\PhpWord\Autoloader::register();
*/

// Template processor instance creation
echo date('H:i:s') , ' Creating new TemplateProcessor instance...' ;
$templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('text.docx');


$templateProcessor->setValue('sss','123');

echo date('H:i:s'), ' Saving the result document...';
$templateProcessor->saveAs('test1.docx');
```

Tested it works!