# Codeigniter and PHPWord

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpword

I'm trying to read some document. So I use PHPWord.

Here what i got in my library.

```
<?php
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

require_once  APPPATH . '/third_party/PhpWord/Autoloader.php';
use PhpWord\Autoloader as Autoloader;
Autoloader::register();

class Word extends Autoloader {

}
```

when i'm going to use it. I have this error :

```
Fatal error: Class 'PhpOffice\PhpWord\Autoloader' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\jdih\application\libraries\Word.php on line 6
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Class 'PhpOffice\PhpWord\Autoloader' not found

Filename: libraries/Word.php

Line Number: 6

Backtrace:
```

I have try this [CodeIgniter PHPWord using as third_party](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26030924/codeigniter-phpword-using-as-third-party) but no help .

Here is the folder of my third_party. How can i fix the problem ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/tree/develop/src/PhpWord) from here

And load the library like this.

```
include_once(APPPATH."third_party/PhpWord/Autoloader.php");
//use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Autoloader;
//use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Settings;
Autoloader::register();
Settings::loadConfig();
```

Comment: should i add this lines `use PhpWord\Autoloader as Autoloader;
Autoloader::register();`?

Comment: well, with or without that. I still get the same error :(

Comment: did you download zip added ??

Comment: yes i did. Your updated answer give different error when i active all lines

Comment: I get this error `Message: Class 'Autoloader' not found`

Comment: check this http://www.ahowto.net/php/creating-ms-word-document-using-codeigniter-and-phpword/

Comment: @YVS1102 happy to help ;)