# Embed phpword into codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, phpword

I want to use the library code in Codeigniter but don't know how to put the latest version of PhpWord into Codeigniter.

Can you give me a sample? I really need a sample code. (show me code in controller, libraries, third_party and show me the necessary folder of PhpWord).

Thanks.

Comment: Did you search on google before posting ?

Comment: I have searched but there is no specific solution. If you know please give me the answer.

Comment: something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39104942/codeigniter-and-phpword ?

Comment: That version is old and incompatible with php7. I also mentioned the latest version above. if this setting will get and  an error like in this topic:https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/issues/732 and cannot be fixed.there is only one way to install the latest version of phpword. hope the helping.